# New Box environement created follow all aspects in figure

Tags: boxes

I try to create the box environment and all figure future to be included in the box environment like (BOX - single column, BOX* - double column, placemnt - [tphb], and seperate auto box label counter BOX 1, BOX 2 and BOX 3....)

But i Don't know how to implement the figure environment logic in new box environment. Please advice.

The below mentioned coding to be fixed single and double column boxes

Single column Box environment

```
 \begin{BOX}[htbp]{caption here}
Box Content here.
\end{BOX}
```

Double column Box Environment (Single column flow)

```
\begin{BOX*}[htbp]{caption here, can be empty}
Box Content here.
\end{BOX*}
```

My output below mentioned here the caption text is available:

**BOX 1 | Caption text.**

Box content here.

Sometimes the caption text is not available. In this case output below mentioned here

**BOX 1 |**

Box content here.

**This box environment covered with framed box.**

Comment: So `BOX` should be a float. I don't understand the difference between what you call "single column" and "double column". Could you explain?

Comment: Maybe `floatrow` package?

Comment: Are you perhaps interested in the `subcaption` package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define (require the `environ` package)

```
\NewEnviron{BOX}[2][htbp]%
{%
\begin{figure}[#1]%
    \BODY
 \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\caption{#2}\fi
\end{figure}%
}

\NewEnviron{BOX*}[2][htbp]%
{%
\begin{figure*}[#1]%
    \BODY
 \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\caption{#2}\fi
\end{figure*}%
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{BOX}[2][htbp]%
{%
\begin{figure}[#1]%
    \BODY
 \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\caption{#2}\fi
\end{figure}%
}

\NewEnviron{BOX*}[2][htbp]%
{%
\begin{figure*}[#1]%
    \BODY
 \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\caption{#2}\fi
\end{figure*}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{BOX}[h]{A caption}
\centering
A figure with caption
\end{BOX}

\begin{BOX}[h]{}
\centering
A figure without caption
\end{BOX}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Notice that you can also use its starred variant `BOX*` to typeset it in two columns when you are in two columns mode.

---

Instead, if you want to create a new floating environment called `BOX` that behaves like a figure, use the `float` package and define:

```
\newfloat{BOX}{htbp}{lob}
```

In this way you create a new floating object called `BOX` and a `.lob` file is created to contain the list of these floats, which can then be recalled through the command

```
\listof{BOX}{List of Boxes}
```

Notice that also in this case you can use its starred variant `BOX*` to typeset it in two columns when you are in two columns mode.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{BOX}{htbp}{lob}
\begin{document}
\listof{BOX}{List of Boxes}
\begin{BOX}[t]
\centering
Some text
\caption{A box}
\end{BOX}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Then, if you want, you can define (require the `environ` package)

```
\NewEnviron{myBOX}[2][htbp]%
{%
\begin{BOX}[#1]%
    \BODY
 \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\caption{#2}\fi
\end{BOX}%
}

\NewEnviron{myBOX*}[2][htbp]%
{%
\begin{BOX*}[#1]%
    \BODY
 \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\caption{#2}\fi
\end{BOX*}%
}
```

so that you can write

```
\begin{myBOX}[t]{caption}
....
\end{myBOX}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{BOX}{htbp}{lob}

\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{myBOX}[2][htbp]%
{%
\begin{BOX}[#1]%
    \BODY
 \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\caption{#2}\fi
\end{BOX}%
}

\NewEnviron{myBOX*}[2][htbp]%
{%
\begin{BOX*}[#1]%
    \BODY
 \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\caption{#2}\fi
\end{BOX*}%
}

\begin{document}
\listof{BOX}{List of Boxes}
\begin{myBOX}[t]{A box}
\centering
Some text
\end{myBOX}
\end{document}
```

The output is the same as above.

Comment: I edit and save my question. My environment name and caption name is same "BOX". But i am unable define the same name. Box content is displayed bottom of the caption. I derived my output in my question. Box environment covered with framebox. I try to define my required output.   But I can't able to get required output. Please advice.